# Exporting selected Items to an SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my attempt to export the selected items of my list, I've gotten to the point where I know where a certain item is ordered within my list, but I can't get the text at that items position into a variable.

```
if (CustomerListbox.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CustomerListbox.GetSelectedIndices().Count(); i++)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = Connection.GetConnection();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            li.Value = Convert.ToString(CustomerListbox.GetSelectedIndices().GetValue(i)); //Determines position within listbox
            li.Text = Convert.ToString(CustomerListbox.Items.FindByValue(li.Value));
            //^^^some magic line of code to do li.text = Items.somethingselected@position5.Value
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "ExportCustomers";
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("myquery", "insert into CustomerSelect(Customers) values('" + li.Text + "')");

        }
        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            throw e2;
        }
        sqlConn.Close();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
if (CustomerListbox.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    foreach(ListItem litem in CustomerListbox.Items)
    {
        if (litem.Selected == True)
        {
            using(SqlConnection sqlConn = Connection.GetConnection())
            {
                using(SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
                {   
                    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                    ListItem li = new ListItem();

                    li.Value = litem.Value; //Determines position within listbox
                    li.Text = litem.Text;

                    sqlCmd.CommandText = "ExportCustomers";
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("myquery", "insert into CustomerSelect(Customers) values('" + li.Text + "')");

                    sqlConn.Open();
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```